# Native pixels size (how to ignore pixel ratio)

Tags: react-native, pixel, resolution-independence

For a simple project which will be deployed to specific devices, I am wondering if it is possible to specify measurements using native pixels, hence ignoring the device dpi (which could be, for instance, overridden by the user in Windows at system level).

Currently, the only solution seems to divide any value for pixel ratio.

Is there a simpler hence more manageable way?

Comment: Other option is multiplying each value for StyleSheet.hairlineWidth

Answer (score 1):

React Native comes with a PixelRatio module that has a method called [`get`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pixelratio.html#get). You must manually divide all of your measurements by the pixel ratio.

1. Start with the number of physical pixels.
2. Divide it by the pixel ratio (`PixelRatio.get()`) to get the corresponding number of logical pixels.
3. Use the number of logical pixels in `StyleSheet.create` and other layout-related methods.
4. React Native and the underlying native UI frameworks will convert the logical pixels back to physical pixels.

You could write a helper method for this if it were to get tedious. This is an idea for an API:

```
StyleSheet.create({
  box: {
    width: physical(100),
    height: physical(75),
  },
});
```

Most of the time though you should work with logical pixels. It's only when you want to precisely control the hardware screen or are interacting with a system without a notion of screen scale (e.g. fetching a JPEG image) that you'd want to work with physical pixels.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which confirms my thoughts. I wonder though if there is a way to pre-process a sheet at "compile" time so that, for instance, a value of "100px" could be converted to "physical(100)".